# Instructions per cycle value of AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4171 HE

Tags: opteron

Does anyone know correct 'instructions per cycle' value for AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4171 HE?

Comment: The best you can do is take the estimated instructions per second and divide by the clock frequency. There's no "one right answer" to this question because the answer depends on the assumptions you make. (Is everything in cache? Are we including floating point or string instructions?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a simple answer to this question - modern CPUs have lots of different instruction types and it's not always possible to say how a given set of instructions is going to be executed. If you want really detailed specific information, though, you could look in [AMD's developer manuals](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/Pages/default.aspx#manuals).